# How to accepts mutliple inputs synchronously based on some count?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am using NodeJS.

I have following task:

1. Accept the user input as "count" for how many times user should input data.
2. Accept the multiple inputs based on count, eg if count is 5, user is allowed to enter input 5 times

The problem I am facing is how to get the user input synchronously, based on the "count" that user has enter first time.

Eg If have C++ code I could simply loop around "count" and accepts the input synchronously.

How to achieve same in NodeJS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to Javascript async-io event-loop architecture implementing a solution is a bit more tricky.
There is a multiple of ways to solve this issue in Javascript and I have provided 2 for you.

## Solution 1

This is the "old" way of doing things. This solution uses `callbacks` and `recursion`. I wouldn't use this personly but it's a good example of manipulation the JS event-loop.

```
const readline = require("readline");
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("Enter inputs count: ", function (countRaw) {
    // validate count
    const count = parseInt(countRaw);
    readMultipuleInputs(count, count, (res) => {
        console.log(res)
        rl.close();
    })
});

function readMultipuleInputs(count, maxCount, cb) {

    if (count == 0) {
        cb([]);
    }

    const currentCount = maxCount-count+1;

    rl.question(`Enter input (${currentCount}/${maxCount}): `, function (res) {
        readMultipuleInputs((count - 1), maxCount, (accumulator) => {
            accumulator.unshift(res);
            cb(accumulator);
        });
    });
}

rl.on("close", function () {
    console.log("\nBYE BYE !!!");
    process.exit(0);
});
```

## Solution 2

This solution is the "modern" way of writing JS. It uses `async` and `await` to allow you to treat your code as it was synchronous.

```
const readline = require("readline");
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.on("close", function () {
    console.log("\nBYE BYE !!!");
    process.exit(0);
});

function rlQuestionPromise(message) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        rl.question(message, resolve);
    });
}

(async function run() {
    const count = await rlQuestionPromise("Enter inputs count: ");

    const accumulator = [];
    for(let i = 0; i<count; i++ ){
        const res = await rlQuestionPromise(`Enter input (${i+1}/${count}): `);
        accumulator.push(res);
    }
    console.log(accumulator);

    rl.close();
})()
```